# For each row of a table run function with every row of another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of points of type `GEOGRAPHY`, call it `T_points`:

```
id   point
1    POINT(-73.964736938476562,  40.7670783996582)
2    POINT(-73.962371826171875,  40.773128509521484)
3    POINT(-73.989463806152344,  40.767578125)
4    POINT(-73.978683471679688,  40.765167236328125)
...
```

and a table of polygons, also of type `GEOGRAPHY`, call it `T_zones`:

```
id  zone
1   POLYGON((-74.1856319999999 40.6916479999999, -74.185911 40.6914499999999, ... ))
3   POLYGON((-73.848596761 40.8716707849999, -73.849876452 40.8721018809999, ... ))
18  POLYGON((-73.8844286139999 40.8668003789999, -73.883625181 40.8672575879999, ... ))
20  POLYGON((-73.8839239579998 40.8644177609999, -73.883960024 40.8645497189999, ... ))
...
```

With the function `ST_COVERS` I can find out if point X is in zone Y by:

```
ST_COVERS(POLYGON((-73.8839239579998 40.8644177609999, -73.883960024 40.8645497189999, ... )),
          POINT(-73.964736938476562,  40.7670783996582),
         )
```

This function returns `TRUE` if it's in the zone and `FALSE` if not.

**Objective**: Find which zone each point is in.

**How to do that**: For each point in `T_points` run this `ST_COVERS` with each zone in `T_zones` and return the `T_zones.id` of the zone that the point is in.

Can someone recommend an efficient way of implementing this?

Something like

```
SELECT get_zone_id(point, T_zones.zones)
FROM T_points
```

would be ideal but no idea how to do that.

Ideal output:

```
id   point                                            zone_id
1    POINT(-73.964736938476562,  40.7670783996582)    1
2    POINT(-73.962371826171875,  40.773128509521484)  3
3    POINT(-73.989463806152344,  40.767578125)        24
4    POINT(-73.978683471679688,  40.765167236328125)  77
```

(the `zone_id` values there are made up)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below way -

```
SELECT id, point, zone_id
FROM T_points 
JOIN T_zones ON ST_WITHIN(point, zone)
```